# Horizontally Aligned Float

Tags: css

How could I make a CSS class called "commenttweet2" that would float 15 pixels to the right of `commenttweet` horizontally aligned?

The PHP / HTML code:

```
 echo "<div class='commenttweet'>";

 echo "<a href='$url'>Tweet this</a>";

 echo "</div>";
```

The CSS:

```
.commenttweet { 
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-top:15px;
            color: #004993;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-top: 2px;               
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. How can it be below, but horizontally aligned to it? You mean have comenttweet2 be below and 15 pixels indented to the right like a thread?

Comment: @robx, by "below", I meant the code "shown below".  I edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what other codes you have, but a real simple startup would be something like this to get you started. Example shown @ http://jsfiddle.net/robx/FSyph/

HTML:

```
<div class='commenttweet'>
    <a href='http://'>Tweet this</a>
</div>
<div class='commenttweet'>
    <a href='http://'>Tweet this 2</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.commenttweet{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the position propertie in the commenttweet class:

```
commenttweet { 
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0px;             
    margin-top:15px;             
    color: #004993;             
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;             
    font-size: 10px;             
    font-weight: bold;             
    height: 15px;             
    padding-bottom: 0px;             
    padding-left: 5px;             
    padding-right: 5px;            
    padding-top: 2px;

}
```

create the following class to commenttweet2 div:

```
.commenttweet2 {    
    position: absolute;
    margin:15px 0 0 15px;

}
```